# How do I develop CUDA application on my ATI, to be later executed on NVIDIA

Tags: cuda, opencl

My computer has an ATI graphics card, but I need to code an algorithm I already have in CUDA, to accerelate the process.  Is that even possible?  If yes does anyone have any link or tutorial from setting up my IDE to coding a simple image processing or passing an image.  I also considered OpenCL but I have not found any information how to do anything with it.

Comment: you can use the device emulator in the CUDA SDK to run it on your CPU or you can take a look at: http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/ if you are on linux

Comment: There is an experimental windows build of gpuocelot. See http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/wiki/Installation#Windows_Build_%28Experimental%29

Comment: @PeterT Correct me if I'm wrong, but for as far as I'm aware there is no longer a device emulator in the SDK (since a 3.x version of CUDA I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is more directed toward the part

> I also considered OpenCL but I have not found any information how to do anything with it.

Check on this NVIDIA site:
http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-gpu-computing-documentation

Scroll down and you find

1. OpenCL Programming Guide

   > This is a detailed programming guide for OpenCL developers.
2. OpenCL Best Practices Guide

   > This is a manual to help developers obtain the best performance from OpenCL.
3. OpenCL Overview for the CUDA Architecture

   > This whitepaper summarizes the guidelines for how to choose the best implementations for NVIDIA GPUs.
4. OpenCL Implementation Notes

   > This document describes the "Implementation Defined" behavior for the NVIDIA OpenCL implementation as required by the OpenCL specification Version: 1.0. The implementation defined behavior is referenced below in the order of it's reference in the OpenCL specification and is grouped by the section number for the specification.

On AMD/ATI you have this site for a brief introduction:
http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/stream-technology/opencl/pages/opencl-intro.aspx

And for more resources check:
http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/stream-technology/Pages/training-resources.aspx

Unless CUDA is a requirement you should consider OpenCL again as you can you use it on both platforms and you state have one and want to develop for the other.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunatly I just found out my graphics cards does not support OpenCL... lucky me...

Comment: `amd.com` links dead

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to take a look at these:

http://blogs.nvidia.com/2011/06/cuda-now-available-for-multiple-x86-processors/

http://www.pgroup.com/resources/cuda-x86.htm

I haven't tried it myself, but the prospect of running CUDA code on x86 seems pretty attractive.