# Dynamically detecting a CUDA enabled NVIDIA card and only then initializing the CUDA runtime: How to do?

Tags: cuda, gpu, cpu, gpgpu

I have an application which has an algorithm, accelerated with CUDA. There is also a standard CPU implementation of it. We plan to release this application for various platforms, so most of the time, there won't be a NVIDIA card to run the accelerated CUDA code. What I want is to first check whether the user's system has a CUDA enabled NVIDIA card and if it does, initializing the CUDA runtime after. If the system does not support CUDA, then I want to execute the CPU path. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043974/how-to-run-my-cuda-application-on-ati-or-intel-card-in-software-mode) question is very similar to mine, but I don't want to use any other libraries other than the plain CUDA runtime. OpenCL is an alternative, but there isn't enough time to implement an OpenCL version of the algorithm for the first release. Without any CUDA existence check, the program will surely crash since it can't find the needed .dll's for the CUDA runtime and we surely don't want that. So, I need advices on how to handle this initialization step.

Comment: woah..that's some work to do man. Way to go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the calls `cudaGetDeviceCount` and `cudaGetDeviceProperties` to find CUDA devices on the running system.  First find out how many, then loop through all the available devices, and inspect the properties to decide which ones qualify.  What I mean by "qualify" depends on your application.  Do you want to require a certain compute capability?  Or need a certain amount of memory?  If there's more than one device, you might want to sort on some criteria, then set the device `cudaSetDevice`.  If there are no devices, or none that are sufficient, then fall back on the CPU code path.

I'd also suggest having some mechanism to force CUDA mode off, in case some user's environment just doesn't work due to driver issues, or an old board, or something else.  You can use a command-line option, or an environment variable, or whatever...

EDITING:
Regarding DLLs, you should package cudart[whatever].dll with your application.  That will ensure that the program starts, and at least the CUDA query functions will operate.

Comment: The first paragraph is actually the answer to question.

Comment: Please follow @Peter's recommendation and ship cudart*.dll with your application.